# Are paths containing directories allowed in AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE?

Tags: gnu, configure, autoconf, automake

The *Autoconf* macro [`AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Input.html#index-AC_005fREQUIRE_005fAUX_005fFILE-60) can be used to register auxiliary files needed during the build process.

> — Macro: `AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE (file)`
>
> Declares that *`file`* is expected in the directory defined above. In Autoconf proper, this macro does nothing: its sole purpose is to be traced by third-party tools to produce a list of expected auxiliary files. For instance it is called by macros like `AC_PROG_INSTALL` (see *Particular Programs*) or `AC_CANONICAL_BUILD` (see *Canonicalizing*) to register the auxiliary files they need.

The files are expected in the directory registered via [`AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Input.html#index-AC_005fCONFIG_005fAUX_005fDIR-58) or a default directory determined as described in the documentation for `AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR` if the macro is not used (referred to as `${auxdir}` in the following).  This is the “directory defined above” in the above quote from the manual.

*Automake* [uses the information](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Optional.html) to add those auxiliary files to the list of distributed files.

> `AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE`
>
> For each `AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE([file])`, Automake will ensure that *`file`* exists in the aux directory, and will complain otherwise. It will also automatically distribute the file. This macro should be used by third-party Autoconf macros that require some supporting files in the aux directory specified with `AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR` above. See *Finding `configure` Input* in *The Autoconf Manual*.

From this documentation – which is all I can find about this topic – I assume that I should also be able to list files in sub-directories of `${auxdir}`.

**However, the following example fails with a funny error.**

Given this directory structure

```
./
./Makefile.am
./build-aux/
./build-aux/bar/
./build-aux/bar/baz.txt
./build-aux/foo.txt
./configure.ac
```

with the following `configure.ac`

```sh
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([example], [1.0], [bugs@example.com])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE([foo.txt])      # this works
AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE([bar/baz.txt])  # this does not work
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
AC_OUTPUT([Makefile])
```

and an empty `Makefile.am`, running `autoreconf -ivs` fails.

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --no-force
configure.ac:5: error: required file 'build-aux/bar/baz.txt' not found
configure.ac:6: installing 'build-aux/install-sh'
configure.ac:6: installing 'build-aux/missing'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

Ironically, the error message names the correct file exactly.

I think that the erratic error message is triggered by the function [`rewrite_inputs_into_dependencies`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/automake.git/tree/bin/automake.in#n3775) but I cannot make sense of the cause of the error due to my limited *Perl* skills.

**So, my question is:**

- Is naming files in sub-directories of `${auxdir}` allowed?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a bug in *Automake*?

If there is a simple workaround to achieve the same effect as if by listing the file in `AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE`, I'd be happy to know that too.  Please note that I'm writing an *Autoconf* macro supposed to be used by other people so I cannot add the files to the `EXTRA_DIST` variable in the `Makefile.am` directly.

Comment: I decided to [report the issue](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-automake/2015-04/msg00001.html) to the *Automake* maintainers and will post an update as I gain new information from there.